# How to send form to self email?

Tags: php, html

This is my contanct.html

```
 <form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
  <p><b>Your Name:</b> <input type="text" name="yourname" /><br />
  <b>Subject:</b> <input type="text" name="subject" /><br />
  <b>E-mail:</b> <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
 Website: <input type="text" name="website"></p>

<p>Do you like this website?
<input type="radio" name="likeit" value="Yes" checked="checked" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="likeit" value="No" /> No
<input type="radio" name="likeit" value="Not sure" /> Not sure</p>

<p>How did you find us?
<select name="how">
<option value=""> -- Please select -- </option>
<option>Google</option>
<option>Yahoo</option>
<option>Link from a website</option>
<option>Word of mouth</option>
<option>Other</option>
</select>

<p><b>Your comments:</b><br />
<textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Send it!"></p>

<p> </p>
<p>Powered by <a href="http://myphpform.com">PHP form</a></p>

</form>
```

This is my php

```
/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your name");
$subject  = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Write a subject");
$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$website  = check_input($_POST['website']);
$likeit   = check_input($_POST['likeit']);
$how_find = check_input($_POST['how']);
$comments = check_input($_POST['comments'], "Write your comments");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
    $website = '';
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Name: $yourname
E-mail: $email
URL: $website

Like the website? $likeit
How did he/she find it? $how_find

Comments:
$comments

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: confirmation.htm');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
```

I got a problem when i upload in domain
It's working but didn't not send to my email of Form
I don't know what is my problem?
I'm newbie in web.dev
sorry for my bad english thanks.

Comment: Is that how the `show_error` function is?

Comment: You need to add `$myemail = "email@example.com";` <= replace with your E-mail address. Plus, your PHP code is incomplete.

Comment: Something is missing after `function show_error($myError)
{` If you want to get it working, follow my first comment and delete `function show_error($myError)
{` if that is all you have for code. Because, I have no idea what it's to be finished with.

Comment: @Fred ill changed that but not working and not send to my email of inquries

Answer (score 0):

I found and figured out what the problem is.

The `function show_error($myError)` was unfinished.

Plus you also needed to add `$myemail = "email@example.com";` replacing it with your E-mail address.

Also make sure this page exists on your server `header('Location: confirmation.htm');`

Tested, working.

```
<?php
/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your name");
$subject  = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Write a subject");
$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$website  = check_input($_POST['website']);
$likeit   = check_input($_POST['likeit']);
$how_find = check_input($_POST['how']);
$comments = check_input($_POST['comments'], "Write your comments");

$myemail = "email@example.com"; // Replace with your E-mail address.

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
    $website = '';
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Name: $yourname
E-mail: $email
URL: $website

Like the website? $likeit
How did he/she find it? $how_find

Comments:
$comments

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */

$headers="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email\r\n";
mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: confirmation.htm');

// echo "ok"; // For testing purposes only
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<b>We apologize for the inconvenience, an error occurred.</b><br />
<?php echo $myError; ?>
<?php
exit();
}
```

Comment: Yah i change that on myemail. but not work and not send to my email

Comment: It worked for me perfectly. I tested it before posting it. Are you using this on a hosted site, or from your local computer? @KrissyNoriega and did you copy my exact code from my answer?

Comment: I got a domain and upload to filezilla but didn't work . i guess i got a problem to upload in filezilla? or nothing happen on that?

Comment: I don't know. Uploading to a server is pretty basic. Make sure both files are in the same place as each other, run the form and make sure that your PHP file is called `sendmail.php` Plus, make sure the hosting you're with does offer `mail()`. Which company is your web hosting? @KrissyNoriega

Comment: I also added another line of code under `/* Send the message using mail() function */` if Mail is available on your server, it may be blocking it because there was no `From:` in the headers and that has been added also. Reload my answer and re-copy the code. @KrissyNoriega

Comment: Yeah they have offer mail(). because i got a task to create simple form to my website and sent to my own email or temporary email .

Comment: I just re-tested many more times (5x) and it's working. Check your Spam then, that's all I can think of now. @KrissyNoriega

Comment: Ok. If you're using a Hotmail/Outlook email, then the chances are even greater it will end up in Spam. @KrissyNoriega

Comment: Working but not send to my email of inquries

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. @KrissyNoriega

Comment: They got success to webpage but didn't send to my email of my form

Comment: I don't know what it could be then. I don't know what else I could say to further help you. You did change the email address in my code from `email@example.com` to yours, right? @KrissyNoriega This line `$myemail = "email@example.com";`

Comment: Ok. Delete your email address now please from the comment (just in case). @KrissyNoriega well, I'm sorry but I'm out of ideas as to why it's not working for you, wish I could help but I can't.

Comment: I got a searched to other blog and they got difference to the code? do you check to new code of php but it is same problem.

Comment: I don't know. Like I said, I can't help any further. Sorry @KrissyNoriega

Comment: Ok sorry for bagging . Thanks alot sorry